# Change Server Settings with JAX-RS New Configuartion "Application" class (without web.xml)?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS (jersey) application using tomcat 7 (servelt 3 support) and I don't have a web.xml file in my application. I used Jersey [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.4.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) class which is an implementation of [Application](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) abstract class for declaring root resource and provider classes as it mentioned in [jersey use guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html). This method can be used as an alternative for web.xml configuation file.

Now I want to config my server (which in my case is tomcat server) like setting customize error page (404), setting filters etc. With web.xml it can be set by using `<error-page>`  and `<filter>` tag, but how these can be set without web.xml and by using ResourceConfig and/or Application class?

Answer (score 3):

From the Jersey documentation you link:

> JAX-RS provides a deployment agnostic abstract class `Application` for declaring root resource and provider classes, and root resource and provider singleton instances.

And from the Javadoc for `Application` you link:

> Defines the components of a JAX-RS application and supplies additional meta-data.

You are asking for configuration that has nothing to do with JAX-RS or Jersey. The `web.xml` configuration of `error-page` or `filter` is completely independent of configuring the JAX-RS application.